# Python 3 == operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, equality

I'm confused as to how the `==` operator works in Python 3. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html), `eq(a, b)` is equivalent to `a == b`. Also `eq` and `__eq__` are equivalent.

Take the following example:

```
class Potato:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print("In Potato's __eq__")
        return True

>> p = Potato()
>> p == "hello"
In Potato's __eq__ # As expected, p.__eq__("hello") is called
True
>> "hello" == p
In Potato's __eq__ # Hmm, I expected this to be false because
True               # this should call "hello".__eq__(p)
>> "hello".__eq__(p)
NotImplemented     # Not implemented? How does == work for strings then?
```

AFAIK, the docs only talk about the `==` -> `__eq__` mapping, but don't say anything about what happens either one of the arguments is not an object (e.g. `1 == p`), or when the first object's `__eq__` is `NotImplemented`, like we saw with `"hello".__eq(p)`.

I'm looking for the general algorithm that is employed for equality... Most, if not all other SO answers, refer to Python 2's [coercion rules](https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/coercion-rules.html), which don't apply anymore in Python 3.

Comment: No `eq` and `__eq__` are not equivalent. You confuse the methods in the `operator` package with generic Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're mixing up the functions in the `operator` module and the methods used to implement those operators. `operator.eq(a, b)` is equivalent to `a == b` or `operator.__eq__(a, b)`, but *not* to `a.__eq__(b)`.

In terms of the `__eq__` method, `==` and `operator.eq` work as follows:

```
def eq(a, b):
    if type(a) is not type(b) and issubclass(type(b), type(a)):
        # Give type(b) priority
        a, b = b, a

    result = a.__eq__(b)
    if result is NotImplemented:
        result = b.__eq__(a)
    if result is NotImplemented:
        result = a is b
    return result
```

with the caveat that the real code performs method lookup for `__eq__` in a way that bypasses instance dicts and custom `__getattribute__`/`__getattr__` methods.

Answer (score 3):

When you do this:

```
"hello" == potato
```

Python first calls `"hello".__eq__(potato)`. That return [`NotImplemented`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#NotImplemented), so Python tries it the other way: `potato.__eq__("hello")`.

Returning `NotImplemented` doesn't mean there's no implementation of `.__eq__` on that object. It means that the implementation didn't know how to compare to the value that was passed in. From https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#NotImplemented:

> Note When a binary (or in-place) method returns NotImplemented the
>   interpreter will try the reflected operation on the other type (or
>   some other fallback, depending on the operator). If all attempts
>   return NotImplemented, the interpreter will raise an appropriate
>   exception. Incorrectly returning NotImplemented will result in a
>   misleading error message or the NotImplemented value being returned to
>   Python code. See Implementing the arithmetic operations for examples.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm confused as to how the == operator works in Python 3. From the docs, `eq(a, b)` is equivalent to `a == b`. Also `eq` and `__eq__` are equivalent.

No that is only the case in the **`operator` module**. The operator module is used to pass an `==` *as a function* for instance. But `operator` has not much to do with vanilla Python itself.

> AFAIK, the docs only talk about the == -> **eq** mapping, but don't say anything about what happens either one of the arguments is not an object (e.g. 1 == p), or when the first object's.

In Python *everything* is an object: an `int` is an object, a "class" is an object", a `None` is an object, etc. We can for instance get the `__eq__` of `0`:

```
>>> (0).__eq__
<method-wrapper '__eq__' of int object at 0x55a81fd3a480>
```

So the equality is implemented in the "`int` class". As specified in the [documentation on the datamodel](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) `__eq__` can return several values: `True`, `False` but any other object (for which the *truthiness* will be calculated). If on the other hand `NotImplemented` is returned, Python will fallback and call the `__eq__` object on the object on the other side of the equation.